# SQL: Employees with more than one department at the same time

Tags: sql, oracle

I am in need of a query that returns `Employee ID, Department, Begin date, End date` for the employee who may be registered in more than one department at the same time, meaning:

The Employee1 could be working in

```
department A: from 01.01.2015 to 31.12.2015 and
department B: from 01.01.2015 to 31.12.2015
```

(the dates overlap)

OR

```
department A from 01.01.2015 to 31.12.2015 and 
department B from 01.06.2015 to 31.12.2018
```

(the dates partially  overlap)

My tables are something like this

```
Employee (Employee ID)
Career (Employee ID, Department ID, BeginDate, EndDate)
Department (DepartmentID)
```

The data that this tables contain are only IDs.
The result should be something like:

```
EmployeeID   Department   BeginDate    EndDate
1            HR                 01.01.2015   31.12.2015
1            ITD                01.01.2015   31.12.2015
2            MR                 01.03.2014   31.12.2018
2            HR                 01.06.2014   31.12.2016
```

With the current department column being an ID like (12HDGH4376SHFJ48).

I am not sure how to write this query. I am not sure what to use in the where clause or if it needs sub queries etc. I am a little bit lost with this. Also I work on Oracle. Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Give us some sample table data, and also the expected result. Have you tried anything? Show us your current query attempt! (Hint: self join, overlaps.)

Comment: You're giving us an expected result, but we don't know starting data... What do you mean with "the same time"? The intervals must completely overlap? ony partially? what begin and end date will you show if you have 2 or 3 overlapping intervals? please add some relevant sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with something like this:

**setup:**

```
create table Employee(EmployeeID number);
create table career(EmployeeID number, DepartmentID number, BeginDate date, EndDate date);
create table department(DepartmentID number, department varchar2(16));
insert into department values (1, 'HR');
insert into department values (2, 'IT');
insert into employee values (20);
insert into employee values (10);
insert into career values (10, 1, to_date('01.01.2015', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('31.12.2015', 'dd.mm.yyyy'));
insert into career values (10, 2, to_date('01.01.2015', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('31.12.2015', 'dd.mm.yyyy'));
insert into career values (20, 1, to_date('01.01.2015', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('31.12.2015', 'dd.mm.yyyy'));
insert into career values (20, 2, to_date('01.06.2015', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('31.12.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy'));
```

**query:**

```
select employeeId, departmentId, beginDate, endDate
from (
      select employeeId, departmentId, beginDate, endDate,
             lag(endDate) over (partition by employeeId order by beginDate) as previousEndDate,
             lead(beginDate) over (partition by employeeId order by beginDate) as nextBeginDate
      from career
         inner join department
           using(departmentId)
     )
where previousEndDate between beginDate and endDate OR
      nextBeginDate between beginDate and endDate
```

This orders the rows by date and checks, for every row, if it overlaps with the preceeding or the next one, with the same employee

Comment: I did some modifications to your query and it worked!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Oracle, Mysql etc?

Also are you querying 3 tables?

Depending on what you are using you should use a rank to identify the record that is the latest one or  the ones that is currently active for the person.

```
    Select
    RANK() OVER (partition by Employee ID BY ORDER BY NVL(END_DATE, CURRENT_DATE)DESC) AS RANK.
```

The rank value will give you the latest record. if you then sub query the whole thing you can then have a where clause like so.
    Where a.rank = 1 
a being the alias of the sub query.

Comment: I am using Oracle and, yes, querying 3 tables. I can't say that I know how to use ranks. Can you give me more info?

Comment: I've edited by original post with an example. Let me know if that helps.